# How fix the DroidSpeech code on a null object reference?

Tags: java, android, null, speech-recognition

I am a newbie at develop android app.

I want to use DroidSpeech (https://github.com/vikramezhil/DroidSpeech)

This code works well on [Android 10]. However, [Android 11] shows the following error.

*DroidSpeech.java*

```
private void startLanguageReceiver()
    {
        Log.i("CONTEXT", context.toString());
        Intent languageDetailsIntent =  RecognizerIntent.getVoiceDetailsIntent(context);

        languageDetailsIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);


        LanguageReceiver languageReceiver = new LanguageReceiver();
        languageReceiver.setOnLanguageDetailsListener(new OnLanguageDetailsListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLanguageDetailsInfo(String defaultLanguage, List<String> otherLanguages) {

                dsProperties.currentSpeechLanguage = defaultLanguage;
                dsProperties.supportedSpeechLanguages = otherLanguages;

                // Initializing the droid speech properties
                initDroidSpeechProperties();

                if(droidSpeechListener != null)
                {
                    // Sending an update with the current speech language and supported speech languages if applicable
                    droidSpeechListener.onDroidSpeechSupportedLanguages(dsProperties.currentSpeechLanguage, dsProperties.supportedSpeechLanguages);
                }
            }
        });

        // Starting the broadcast receiver to get the language details
        context.sendOrderedBroadcast(languageDetailsIntent, null, languageReceiver, null, Activity.RESULT_OK, null, null);
    }
```

this is error CODE

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Intent android.content.Intent.addFlags(int)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.Jachi3kki.DroidSpeech.DroidSpeech.startLanguageReceiver(DroidSpeech.java:108)
        at com.example.Jachi3kki.DroidSpeech.DroidSpeech.<init>(DroidSpeech.java:83)
        at com.example.Jachi3kki.fragment.ViewPagerMainFragment.onCreate(ViewPagerMainFragment.kt:42)
```

DroidSpeech.java:108 this

```
Intent languageDetailsIntent =  RecognizerIntent.getVoiceDetailsIntent(context);
```

DroidSpeech.java:83

```
startLanguageReceiver();
```

I tried to fix it but failed.

It looks like all variables are initialized, but there is an error somewhere.

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

To fix this issue for Android 11, follow the below steps

**Step 1**: [Download](https://github.com/vikramezhil/DroidSpeech/archive/refs/tags/v2.0.3.zip) the code zip and change in DroidSpeech.java on line 103

Replace this: `Intent languageDetailsIntent = RecognizerIntent.getVoiceDetailsIntent(context);`

With this: Intent languageDetailsIntent =  Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);

**Step 2**: Copy the `com.vikramezhil.droidspeech` pakage to my project and change the app gradle

Replace this: `compile 'com.github.vikramezhil:DroidSpeech:v2.0.3’`

With this: `implementation project(path: ':droidspeech')`

Comment: thank you sir...but this code does not work on [compileSdkVersion 30]...
I dont know why does not work this code :(

Comment: @kanzu For SDK 30, you need to use the updated version of this SDK i.e https://github.com/vikramezhil/DroidSpeech2.0 and make the above kind of similar custom implementation by following this https://github.com/vikramezhil/DroidSpeech2.0/issues/17#issuecomment-801908813